# Powershell Scheduled Task At Startup Repeating

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a Scheduled Task with the following Trigger:
 - Startup
 - Run every 5 minutes
 - Run indefinitely

In the GUI I can do this easily by selecting:
 - Begin the task: at startup
And in the Advanced tab:
 - Repeat task every: 5 minutes
 - For a duration of: indefinitely

But I'm having trouble doing it with Powershell.

My troubled code:
`$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)`
`$duration = ([timeSpan]::maxvalue)`
`$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration`

It won't take the RepetitionInterval and RepetitionDuration parameters. But I need that functionality. 
How could I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the task literally with a "Startup" trigger and a repetition, it seems you have to reach in to COM (or use the TaskScheduler UI, obviously..).

```
# Create the task as normal
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "myApp.exe"
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -TaskName "My Task" -Description "Data import Task" -User $username -Password $password

# Now add a special trigger to it with COM API.
# Get the service and task
$ts = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$ts.Connect()
$task = $ts.GetFolder("\").GetTask("My Task").Definition

# Create the trigger
$TRIGGER_TYPE_STARTUP=8
$startTrigger=$task.Triggers.Create($TRIGGER_TYPE_STARTUP)
$startTrigger.Enabled=$true
$startTrigger.Repetition.Interval="PT10M" # ten minutes
$startTrigger.Repetition.StopAtDurationEnd=$false # on to infinity
$startTrigger.Id="StartupTrigger"

# Re-save the task in place.
$TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE=6
$TASK_LOGIN_PASSWORD=1
$ts.GetFolder("\").RegisterTaskDefinition("My Task", $task, $TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, $username, $password, $TASK_LOGIN_PASSWORD)
```

Comment: Great example! Also, it is possible to avoid this COM approach, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61646465/2943191

Answer (score 3):

`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` uses parameter sets.  When you specify that you want the scheduled task to start up "at logon" you are restricting yourself to the following parameter set:

```
Parameter Set: AtStartup
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger [-AtStartup] [-RandomDelay <TimeSpan> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

What may be more beneficial is if you use your "at startup" scheduled task to register a new scheduled task to run every five minutes using the "once" parameter set:

```
Parameter Set: Once
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger [-Once] -At <DateTime> [-RandomDelay <TimeSpan> ] [-RepetitionDuration <TimeSpan> ] [-RepetitionInterval <TimeSpan> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Your Scheduled Task Trigger should successfully be assigned once you are using the correct parameter set.

Comment: any example to get inspired from ?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61646465/2943191

It is actually relatively simple, once a working example is written, of course.

Instead of `-AtLogOn` use `-AtStartup`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it’s worth, I too ran into this issue as I was particularly perturbed that this functionality was pulled from PowerShell for -AtStartup.  However, upon further review, the same functionality can be performed by just be using -Once and configuring it to repeat.  In the OP’s case of having this run every five minutes, it probably won’t make a difference if this is run at startup or five minutes thereafter.

I have confirmed this with -Once and then configuring it to repeat.  It will also perform the repeats when the system is restarted.  This is somewhat different from @BryceMcDonald’s answer in that you don’t need to create two triggers—just create the -Once one and you’ll be good to go.