# Use Powershell to add property "On Workstation Unlock" to scheduled task

Tags: powershell

I have a task with two triggers. The first one starts with logon of any user 
and runs every 3 minutes indefinitely. 
The second one starts when "on workstation UNlock". I want to also run this 
second trigger every 10 minutes and indefinitely after triggered. I have the 
following part that corresponds to "On Workstation Unlock", but how do I get 
everything together?

```
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task"
$Task.Triggers.Repetition.Duration = "" 
$Task.Triggers.Repetition.Interval = "PT10M"

    $stateChangeTrigger = Get-CimClass `
         -Namespace ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler `
         -ClassName MSFT_TaskSessionStateChangeTrigger

    $onUnlockTrigger = New-CimInstance `
        -CimClass $stateChangeTrigger `
        -Property @{
        StateChange = 8  # TASK_SESSION_STATE_CHANGE_TYPE.TASK_SESSION_UNLOCK (taskschd.h)
    } `
       -ClientOnly
```

Comment: This is an odd request.  What is your goal?

Answer (score 4):

You can do so in the following way (updating the task twice):

```
# Create the trigger class for $T2
$StateChangeTrigger = Get-CimClass `
    -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler `
    -ClassName MSFT_TaskSessionStateChangeTrigger

# Define triggers (the type)
$T1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
$T2 = New-CimInstance `
    -CimClass $StateChangeTrigger `
    -Property @{StateChange = 8} `
    -ClientOnly

# Update the task; Get its new settings
Set-ScheduledTask 'Task' -Trigger $T1,$T2
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Task'

# Set triggers options
$Task.Triggers[0].Repetition.Interval = 'PT3M'
$Task.Triggers[1].Repetition.Interval = 'PT10M'

# Final task update
$Task | Set-ScheduledTask
```

There is also a good example by @Jarrad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52359359/2943191) on how to modify triggers for your situation but using the COM approach.

### # UPDATE

It is possible to do the above without modifying the task twice by creating the appropriate CIM instance for the repetition pattern:

```
# Create the trigger class for $T2
$StateChangeTrigger = Get-CimClass `
    -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler `
    -ClassName MSFT_TaskSessionStateChangeTrigger

# Create the repetition pattern class
$RepetitionPattern = Get-CimClass `
    -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler `
    -ClassName MSFT_TaskRepetitionPattern

# Define a new repetition pattern
$R = New-CimInstance `
    -CimClass $RepetitionPattern `
    -Property @{Interval = 'PT3M'} `
    -ClientOnly

# Define triggers
$T1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
$T1.Repetition = $R
$T2 = New-CimInstance `
    -CimClass $StateChangeTrigger `
    -Property @{StateChange = 8;
                Repetition = $R} `
    -ClientOnly
$T2.Repetition.Interval = 'PT10M'

# Update the task and done
Set-ScheduledTask 'Task' -Trigger $T1,$T2
```

---

*The corresponding reference links:*

- [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger)
- [Set-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/set-scheduledtask)
- [Register-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask) (to create a new task instead of
  modifying an existing one)

Comment: The update version do not work on Windows 2012 R2, "The property 'Repetition' cannot be found on this object". Works great on Windows 2016.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about the Windows Server editions! It's good that at least the first method works for the 2012 R2 version. But no wonder it's like that, as these things are in constant development. Or, maybe it is a line continuation problem. Try putting `-Property @{StateChange = 8; Repetition = $R}` on a single line. And, at which line do you exactly get the error?

Comment: @zexal985236, if this answer has solved the problem you posed in the question, you should accept the answer.